# Order By Random is creating errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

Here is what i want to use and I was using:

```
$sql="SELECT * from channel ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6 ";

$rs = $conn->
Execute($sql);

$channellist = $rs->
getrows();
```

But this creates errors, the whole site goes blank.
In the server error logs this is the error:

```
[28-Jul-2013 09:53:37 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getrows() on a non-object in /home/hotspitt/public_html/cache/templates_c/%%C3^C37^C3724EE2%%head1.tpl.php on line 60
```

Removing line 60 ( `$channellist = $rs->getrows();` ) makes it work. 
and also changing it to:

```
$sql="SELECT * from channel ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 6 ";

$rs = $conn->
Execute($sql);

$channellist = $rs->
getrows();
```

makes it work. So I think there is something wrong with the rand function. I can't understand why rand() function is not working.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: What is `$conn` ? And does the query work straight in SQL ?

Comment: I think your missin the ASC/DESC in the query "SELECT * FROM `channel` ORDER BY rand() desc LIMIT 6" try out this?

Comment: pretty sure the ASC/DESC has nothing to do with that since this fiddle works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e76/2
But to know how $conn is declared/initialized would be interesting

Comment: I know both the queries are right. As rand() function was working few days ago but after installing nginx all this happened.
And now i can't use rand() function, i have to stick with order by Desc. I have no idea about it why it is so.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_details order by rand() limit 10
```

working, now problem either your table name
or your  library used for executing sql

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with Table name and Library. As this:
$sql="SELECT * from channel ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 6 ";

$rs = $conn-> Execute($sql);

$channellist = $rs-> getrows();

is Working.

But when it comes to rand(). it just go blank.

Comment: get more info about api using to execute sql statement, there must be some flag NOT TO OMMIT MYSQL FUNCTION.This library is just ignoring your rand function to string, hence you are getting blank output,do research on api